# Service/API calls in Angular

Tags: angular

I had started learning angular. I observed that API calls are doing within the ngOnInit. Why not inside the constructor as we are doing dependency Injection also there.
I know that component will be completely getting loaded inside the onInit function.
So, Is there any problem if we access/call api data in constructor before loading component, if so in which way it will be ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor should be used for dependency injection and to create/init objects. It is JS engine calls constructor and not Angular.

The ngOnInit() method is a special lifecycle hook and give us a signal that Angular has finished initialising the component. ngOnInit() gives us a guarantee that bindings are available and allows you to invoke method calls.
It’s a common practice to use ngOnInit to perform initialization logic even if this logic doesn’t depend on dependency injection, DOM or input bindings.

Comment: "bindings are available and allows you to invoke method calls"  Can you say, which type of methods or bindings ? do you mean like interpolation with 2 way bindings and so on..?

Comment: Input property for example, because Input need to pass at change detection. It will be undefined in constructor